# PyQT QFileDialog - get full directory including IP of disk

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

I'd like to get full path of my directory, something like:

```
//192.168.1.23/D/test/test/aaaa/
```

or

```
//192.168.1.23/D:/test/test/aaaa/
```

How can I get QFileDialog to give me the IP address of the HDD that I have selected?

Currently using

```
self.project= str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,  "Select Directory", lastDir))
```

tried going via `os.path.dirname(self.project)` but that only ever goes down to `D:\`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where I found it but here is the option I followed at the end. I let user decide then which device to use for location

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
p =[]
for ifaceName in interfaces():
    addresses = [i['addr'] for i in ifaddresses(ifaceName).setdefault(AF_INET, [{'addr':'No IP addr'}] )]
    p.append(ifaceName.join(addresses))   

print p[0],p[1]
print p
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible in PyQt directly with `QFileDialog` what you can do instead is to get the ip address of your machine with another method and then concatenate that with the file path, something like this. QFileDialog isn't 'Network aware'

```
import socket
def get_ip_addr():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    return s.getsockname()[0]

ip = get_ip_addr()

path = self.project= str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,  "Select Directory", lastDir))

file_path = '//{}/{}'.format(ip, path) # or what ever formatting suits you
```

You can also take a look at QNetworkInterface http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qnetworkinterface.html#interfaceFromName if you're interested in other addresses on your machine, but the example above just returns the ip address that's used to route to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: This is the right idea for a solution, but you can get it without actually connecting to any remote endpoint. I'd use something like `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` instead.

Comment: that may return `127.0.0.1` on machine that have the hostname set to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`...Linux machines apparently, but op seems to be using windows, so it might work on windows but i'm not sure

Comment: Hey I did think of that. But if I try to list network drive that is lets say //192.168.1.50/E and I run the gethostname() opt or the socketname the result will be //192.168.1.23/E... directing me to wrong location? Not only that if I have 2 network cards. I think I may need 2 ip addresses for given driver. Honestly I haven't checked it yet but I'll give it a go maybe I'm wrong here... Thanks!